# Can't play .mp3 audio file as Background music

Tags: wpf, mp3, mediaelement, background-music

I want to play my audio file as background music when my window opens in my Wpf project.I use MediaElement control. Like

```
<MediaElement MediaOpened="myMediaElement_MediaOpened" MediaFailed="myMediaElement_MediaFailed"
                  Volume="10" x:Name="myMediaElement" IsMuted="False"  
                  LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Manual"
                  Source="Resources/Media/Audio/StartPageMusic.mp3"/>
```

I can not get any sound when window opens. And can not catch any Exception. What is the problem in it? Or have I done anything wrong?
 I handled the event and try to play file.

```
 private void myMediaElement_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaElement _element = sender as MediaElement;
        _element.Play();
    }
```

My file is in folder Resources/Media/Audio. This folder is in my project. And I have set my audio file as CONTENT for BuildAction and CopyAlways for CopyToOutputDirectory in the Properties window.

Answer (score 1):

As i can see the problem is that  ***MediaOpened*** is not raised.

The reason is this :

> ' **MediaElement.MediaOpened Event** *Occurs when media loading has finished*.'

MSDN : [MediaElement.MediaOpened Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.mediaopened(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you want to play the mp3 file as background music when the main window opens then you can add WindowLoaded event and there you can start the playing.

```
 public MainWindow()
 {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
 }

 void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
        myMediaElement.Play();
 }
```